# Rolling my own extremely light weight 'event' system

Tags: python, events, eval, observer-pattern

I am using Python 2.7, and I want to write a small library that is a kind of 'event system'. Basically, I have field objects (currently only two attributes, but that may change later), and criterion objects which contain fields.

The criterion class is passed an expression which contains the field objects, and the Criterion class is an observer to the fields so that whenever one of the contained fields attributes (e.g. value etc) changes, it triggers the Criterion class to reevaluate itself to check whether the expression is true.

If the expression evaluates as true, then the Criterion class does something - for now probably print to screen.

```
class Field(Object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, value):
        self.id = id
        self.name =  name
        self.value = value

    def set_value(newval):
        self.value = newval

    def __repr__(self):
        print self.id, self.name, self.value



# A criterion is constructed with an expression containing field objects
# It 'listens' to changes in the field attributes and reevaluates itself and checks if expression is now true
# When the expression is true, it prints to the console
class Criterion(Object):
    def __init__(self, express):
        parse_expression(express) # parses expression to get field objects (is this necessary?)
        self.fields = {}  # dictionary of fields


    # call back when one of the parsed and observed fields changes
    def upon_field_change(field):
        if eval_expression():
            # do something
            print "Criterion evaluated true upon field change: %s", field
            pass

    # evaluate expression with current field objects
    # returns boolean
    def eval_expression():
        pass


    # evaluates bolean True/False
    def __nonzero__():
        eval_expression()
```

The code snippet above is of the top of my head, my question is:

1. Am I going along the right route or is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?
2. Is there a better way of writing the code above?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not reinvent the wheel, there is an excellent events library for Python
called [louie](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Louie/1.1) (was `pydispatcher` before), just use it. It allows to emit signals from
any Python object, and to execute callbacks. It handles references properly, and also
has other features.

In your scenario, [louie](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Louie/1.1) can be used to emit changes from the Field objects to the Criterion objects for example.